# Classic ASP on Azure WebSite, enable IIS

Tags: azure, asp-classic, azure-devops

I'm on a mac using brackets editor and dropbox linked deployment to an azure website.

The code I'm trying to run is classic ASP JScript.  From SE/Google its seems i need to run a startup.cmd file containing the line **start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-AS** but I can't figure out where to deploy this to to make to run.  I don't have visual studio or a PC.

I'm also trying to use the Monaco editor in Visual Studio Team Services. Please help.

Comment: Is there anything on a Mac which will let you open a remote terminal session to your server, like RDP on Windows.  You'll need to do that to enable classic ASP, then you can just ftp your files across.  (Or perhaps you could just borrow someone's PC for half an hour)

Comment: Yes, MS RDP is on mac, but the Azure Shared Webserver does not seem to support RDP sessions like a full VM does, I can't find a setting anywhere in the azure portal if it does.   All the examples I have seen seem to require creating a visual studio project, so I would need to borrow a PC, download VS (which version?) all just to get a server to run a single line command - really?

Comment: I run Visual Web Developer 2010, which is the free, entry level version, that should be adequate for what you want to do.  I've done a bit of googling myself though.  It would appear that you only need VS to add a few lines to a file with standard XML syntax.  You can do that with any text editor you like, it's just that VS is the most obvious thing to use if you're on Windows.  See this link http://khailiangtech.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/windows-azure-how-to-enable-classic-asp-support/ and download an empty project from http://cdn.blog.smarx.com/files/ClassicASP_source.zip

Comment: The article seems to pinpoint adding a startup section into the ServiceDefinition.csdef XML file, I'm not clear what the other ten files in the solution do. I understand this is the 'easiest' way if you are a VS developer but it seem like a huge amount of overhead just to get IIS to load the scripting module for asp. I assume that if I can get the file in the right place and restart the server it will enable asp. One of the other articles mentioned getting the startup.cmd file into the bin directory. FTP onto the server there isn't a bin directory to be seen.

Comment: I've always had the RDP option so I'm guessing a bit here.  If you can't see a bin directory then try creating one at root level.  web.config should also go in the bin directory, it performs a similar role to .htaccess.  Some of the files in the project are only there to tell VS which files are in the project.  Microsoft stopped developing Classic in 2002 in favour of .net, and it probably annoys them somewhat that people still want to use it. They don't make it straightforward. They dropped support for Classic in VS2008, then restored in in Service Pack 1 when people protested

Answer (score 3):

Classic ASP is ALREADY enabled on the specific azurewebsites.net website and do not need a .csdef or startup.cmd file.

My code would not run because it was moved from a windows 2008 server that had IIS configured with the default asp language as JScript.  The azure websites default to VBScript, so it is necessary to add a `<% @ language="javascript" %>` to the top of each .asp file.

Yes Microsoft had server side javascript long before node.js was even a twinkle in the eye.

Comment: It's often something simple like that.  VBScript has always been the default ASP scripting language for out of the box IIS, but obviously this can be changed in IIS Manager.  I also find it amusing how the "cool kids" using node think they invented server side JS :)